# entity framework 6 и sSQLite

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Получаю ошибки:
SQLite error (1): no such table: __MigrationHistory
SQLite error (1): no such table: __MigrationHistory
SQLite error (1): no such table: EdmMetadata

На сколкьо могу судить, EF создает какие-то свои служебные таблицы, как бы это вылечить?

Comment: EF6 имеет весьма посредственную поддержку SQLite, поэтому, я бы Вам не рекомендовал использовать эту связку. В частности, не поддерживается создание базы данных и миграции.

Comment: @ixSci А можете посоветовать какую-нибудь встраиваемую бд?

Comment: Попробуйте [SQL Server Compact Edition](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_Compact_Edition), поддержка этой базы есть в EF6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы EF6 не создавал свои служебные таблицы просто нужно отключить инициализацию модели В конструкторе контекста:

```
    public MyContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
    }
```